# How to prevent SqsListener from spamming error logs

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator, sqslistener

I have a Spring Boot application that uses an `io.awspring.cloud.sqs` SQS listener

```java
@SqsListener(value = "${spring.cloud.aws.sqs.queue-name}",)
public String processSesEvent(EmailSqsMessage message) {
  [code]
}
```

When the application is deployed to Kubernetes, there is a spam of identical error logs (~10k in 10 seconds). The logs:

```
Error polling for messages in queue [queue name]

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.239.232.173:443
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.errorAsCompletionException(CompletableFutureUtils.java:65)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.lambda$execute$0(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeAttemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:184)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$null$0(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:103)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.completeResponseFuture(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:240)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$executeHttpRequest$3(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection refused: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.239.232.173:443
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:218)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:182)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/3.239.232.173:443
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:335)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After that burst of errors, they stop, and the SQS listener works as expected.

How could I prevent this spam from happening?

I tried implementing a health indicator and including it in Kubernetes:

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SqsHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
  private final SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient;
  @Value("${spring.cloud.aws.sqs.ses-event-queue}")
  private String queueName;

  @Override
  public Health health() {
    try {
      sqsAsyncClient.getQueueUrl(GetQueueUrlRequest.builder().queueName(queueName).build()).get();
      return Health.up().build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return Health.down(e).build();
    }
  }
}
```

`application.yml`:

```yaml
management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
      group:
        liveness:
          include:
            - livenessState
            - sqs
```

`deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
startupProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
    port: 8080
  failureThreshold: 10
  periodSeconds: 5
  initialDelaySeconds: 20
```

This did include the health indicator in the liveness endpoint, however it did not fix the issue.

Added a line to log the health check:

```java
var result = sqsAsyncClient.getQueueUrl(GetQueueUrlRequest.builder().queueName(queueName).build()).get();
log.info("sqsAsync call result: {}", result);
```

And looking at at the logs, seems like the call to that endpoint is successfull and the liveness check passes before the spam of error logs happen.

The service uses istio proxy as a sidecar, so there is a theory that the spring boot app is up before istio pod is ready and that causes the connection issue, so I've also tried adding an annotation as suggested [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/common-problems/injection/), but to no avail.

Edit: After some more investigation, seems like the spam of logs happen on the pod that is beign shut down, rather the one that is being created on deployment.